# can not set property of undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have taken the code from here:

[link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

Snapshot of error:

[image: snapshot]

I get error at `newUser.local.email    = email;` 
of this code:

```
 passport.use('local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
 function(req, email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser            = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.local.email    = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });    

        });

    }));
```

In Sample------> models.
 I have User.js that contains the schema for User sign up.
and looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,

});
```

What looks wrong here?Can I please get some directions?

Comment: Seems like `new User()` return something which doesn't contain a `local` object property so when you try to add a property to `local` it fails. Console log `newUser` and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Please post text instead of images.

Comment: Silly me. You were absolutely correct. Thanks a ton :)